# Celery Task exists prematurely when trying to access Django model

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a celery task that needs to access a django model. my code in tasks.py is

```
@app.task
def crawlweb(listing_file_obj, marketplace):
    logger = logging.getLogger("gbp_web.odsa")
    logger.info('Started the task')
    listing_file_obj.status="In Progress"
    listing_file_obj.save()
```

and I call this from my views.py code

```
def prepare_urls_to_scrap(listing_file_obj, marketplace):
    crawlweb.delay(listing_file_obj, marketplace)
    logger.info('Submitted a crawling task')
```

when I do this I get this error

```
[2016-04-27 17:41:34,792: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-5' pid:7362 exited with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)'
[2016-04-27 17:41:34,804: ERROR/MainProcess] Task odsa.tasks.crawlweb[ad90ca39-488e-4c94-ac28-88740562e934] raised unexpected: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/amer/repository/gbp_web/env/lib/python2.7/site- packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1175, in mark_as_worker_lost
human_status(exitcode)),
```

if I comment out any access to an object, like removing the following line

```
    listing_file_obj.save()
```

The task works fine. Every time I try to access a django model, it exists prematurely. I trying running the code without it being a task, and without using celery, it works fine.

Here is how my celery settings look like

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERYD_OPTS = "--concurrency=1"
```

and here is the celery.py file

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'gbp_web.settings')

app = Celery('gbp_web')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600
)
```

I am using a Mac El Capitan, redis broker, django 1.9.2 scrapy 1.0.5 and celery 3.1.23

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yo haven't actually called this via Celery. You'd need to do `crawlweb.delay(listing_file_obj, marketplace)` for that.

Comment: you are right, I tried that with .delay but it didn't work. I must have put the function call after trying to make sure the function crawlweb. I will edit this